# External properties Sign and Encrypt SOAP Messages with Apache CXF

Tags: apache, cxf, jboss5.x, ws-security

I am trying to externalize my sign and encrypt properties file. 
But if I use the absolut path the context cannot get it.

¿Do you have and idea of how can I do?
¿How can I include an absolut path in my jboss classpath?

I am using jboss 5.1

I have this:

```html
<entry key="user" value="${user.ws.security.firma}"/>
<entry key="signatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference"/>
<entry key="signatureParts" value="{Element}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body"/>
<entry key="signaturePropFile" value="sign.properties"/>
<entry key="passwordCallbackClass" value="es.minhap.carpeta.front.ws.micc.security.ClientPasswordCallback"/>
```

I want something like this

```html
<entry key="user" value="${user.ws.security.sign}"/>
<entry key="signatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference"/>
<entry key="signatureParts" value="{Element}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body"/>
<entry key="signaturePropFile" value="C:/workspace/sign.properties"/>
<entry key="passwordCallbackClass" value="es.micc.security.ClientPasswordCallback"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently can't use absolute paths in CXF settings for encryption and signed, the files are loaded from the classpath by [WSS4J](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.ws.security/wss4j/1.5.9/org/apache/ws/security/components/crypto/CryptoFactory.java#CryptoFactory.getProperties%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.ClassLoader%29):

Alternatively you can put your properties files in conf directory of JBoss. This directory is part of the classpath or add a custom directory to classpath in `conf/jboss-service.xml` as follows:

```
<classpath codebase="${jboss.server.lib.url}" archives="*"/>
<classpath codebase="${jboss.common.lib.url}" archives="*"/>
<classpath codebase="file:/C:/mycustomconfigdir/" archives="*"/>
```